# Create a histogram showing month and year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can create only a histogram with month or year seperately but not with month and year at the same time in the x-axis.

This is the data I have

| Year | Month | stroke_victims |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | 1 | 40 |
| 2005 | 2 | 50 |
| 2005 | 3 | 48 |
| 2005 | 4 | 52 |
| 2005 | 5 | 32 |
| 2005 | 6 | 21 |
| 2005 | 7 | 23 |
| 2005 | 8 | 56 |
| 2005 | 9 | 43 |
| 2005 | 10 | 11 |
| 2005 | 11 | 12 |
| 2005 | 12 | 15 |
| 2006 | 1 | 40 |
| 2006 | 2 | 50 |
| 2006 | 3 | 48 |
| 2006 | 4 | 52 |
| 2006 | 5 | 32 |
| 2006 | 6 | 21 |
| 2006 | 7 | 23 |
| 2006 | 8 | 56 |
| 2006 | 9 | 43 |
| 2006 | 10 | 11 |
| 2006 | 11 | 12 |
| 2006 | 12 | 15 |
| 2007 | 1 | 40 |
| 2007 | 2 | 50 |
| 2007 | 3 | 48 |
| 2007 | 4 | 52 |
| 2007 | 5 | 32 |
| 2007 | 6 | 21 |
| 2007 | 7 | 23 |
| 2007 | 8 | 56 |
| 2007 | 9 | 43 |
| 2007 | 10 | 11 |
| 2007 | 11 | 12 |
| 2007 | 12 | 15 |

For year the code is like this

```
ggplot(stroke,aes(x=Year,y=stroke_victims)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("Stroke victim patterns across the year 2005-2007")
```

For year the code is like this

```
ggplot(stroke,aes(x=Month,y=stroke_victims)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("Stroke victim patterns by Months")
```

Is it possible to create a code which show january 2005, then february 2005 and so on and with the month name?

Comment: Hi again Jonathan :) Could you please use the `dput` function on your dataframe so you can copy your dataframe in your question. This will allow people to copy it, launch it and propose easily and answer

Comment: @YacineHajji I agree, but in a pinch I use `read.so::read.md` from https://github.com/alistaire47/read.so

Comment: I am very new to stackoverflow. How do I use dput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the month *name*:

```r
stroke$Month_text <- month.abb[stroke$Month]
head(stroke)
#   Year Month stroke_victims Month_text
# 1 2005     1             40        Jan
# 2 2005     2             50        Feb
# 3 2005     3             48        Mar
# 4 2005     4             52        Apr
# 5 2005     5             32        May
# 6 2005     6             21        Jun
```

or one can convert it to a date and use `format(.., format="%B")` (see `?strptime` for `%`-codes). I'll use `month.abb` for now.

From here, we can facet on `Month_text`. However, it's going to be sorted lexicographically which is incorrect:

```r
ggplot(stroke,aes(x=Month_text,y=stroke_victims)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Stroke victim patterns by Months") +
  facet_grid(Year ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot with incorrect month sort]

With any question in [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) that includes "order of ...", we use factors.

```r
stroke$Month_text <- factor(month.abb[stroke$Month], levels = month.abb)
ggplot(...) + ... # unchanged from above
```

[image: ggplot with correct sorted months]

---

Data

```r
stroke <- structure(list(Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), stroke_victims = c(40L, 50L, 48L, 52L, 32L, 21L, 23L, 56L, 43L,  11L, 12L, 15L, 40L, 50L, 48L, 52L, 32L, 21L, 23L, 56L, 43L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 40L, 50L, 48L, 52L, 32L, 21L, 23L, 56L, 43L, 11L, 12L, 15L), Month_text = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a continuous graph, see below. Otherwise use facet_grid like in r2evans answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(forcats)

stroke %>% 
  mutate(year_month_lab = forcats::as_factor(paste(Year, month.abb[Month], sep = " "))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year_month_lab, y=stroke_victims)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  ggtitle("Stroke victim patterns by Year Month") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))
```

[image]